# PHP: strtotime revered return strange date?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datetime

I am using php `strtotime` and mysql `datetime` for a simple countdown to a certain date.

I also use jQuery to countdown.

my jquery strtotime time is like this: `1443661380000`

if I run my jquery countdown without any php, it works just fine and counts down properly.

However, when I use the mysql `datetime` and php strtotime like so : `$long = strtotime("$fes_events_date");` my jquery countdown stops working.

so I tried to reverse the jquery strtotime which is `1443661380000` so I can see what it looks like in case I am missing something in my php strtotime.

so I did this:

```
    $hin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1443661380000);
echo $hin;
```

and the output of that is something strange which is the following:

```
47717-10-22 18:00:00
```

so the question that I have is that How can I convert my datetime mysql using php strtotime so I get the same kind of output in order to make my jquery countdown to work?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That timestamp is in milliseconds. You need to convert it to seconds to work with strtotime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know that measuring [UNIX / Epoch Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is usually done in one of two ways, either in seconds, or in milliseconds since `January, 1 1970`.

It would appear to me that you have a time in milliseconds, whereas the function that you are trying to use is converting it as if it were in seconds, therefore you are off by a factor of 1000.

Try diving your time by 1000 and then passing it into the converter.

```
1000ms/1000 = 1s
1443661380000ms / 1000 = 144366138s

144366138s -> Date -> GMT: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 01:03:00
```

Answer (score 2):

The unix timestamp, the second argument to the `date` function, is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

For reasons that are lost to the mists of history, the javascript timestamp is the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch.  The PHP `strToTime` function doesn't recognize that and can't do its magic.  You'll need to manually convert your milliseconds to seconds.

```
$hin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", (1443661380000/1000));
echo $hin;
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change,

```
$hin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1443661380000);
```

to

```
$mil=1443661380000;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
$hin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);
```